# Using a cert with svn

Tags: svn, certificate

I wish to use a certificate with Linux command-line svn.

I obtained my certificate using IE on Windows, and exported it. Then I copied it to Linux. Here's my experience (below). I'd like to **a) fix what's wrong here** and **b) understand the relationship between Subversion and Apache** in the case where the repository isn't on my local host, but on a remote host.

In Googling to figure out a solution and understand it, I keep seeing Apache installation and configuration instructions. Is it the case that, despite not hosting the repository locally or making it available to others from my host, I still must install and configure Apache? Those discussions always seem to fall in the context of serving up a repository to others and I'm not trying to do that.

I'm only trying to consume a Subversion repository from a remote host in my company using a certificate generated by my company's certificate authority.

```
russ@russ-elite-book:~/certificates> ll
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 russ russ 4060 2010-12-07 15:36 mybadge.pfx

russ@russ-elite-book:~/certificates> svn co https://xyz.acme.com/svn/xyz/trunk
Authentication realm: https://xyz.acme.com:443
Client certificate filename: ./mybadge.pfx
Passphrase for '/home/russ/certificates/mybadge.pfx': 
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS \
       request for 'https://xyz.acme.com/svn/xyz/trunk'
```

Copious thanks to any and all who can help.

Russ

Comment: The block from your apache config file where it sets up the certificate authentication would probably be helpful as well.

Comment: I did go to try it on Windows and TortoiseSVN. It failed similarly. So, this answers both questions, I think: a) my certificate appears bad (so I'll have to take that up with the issuing authority) and b) I do not have to mess with Apache vhost configuration files and the like, at least not unless I want not to have to type in the path to the cert--something for another moment once any of this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, based on that response, your certificate doesn't have permission to access that svn host; it is probably a permissions issue on the server.

Comment: Finally worked out late yesterday... it turns out that the issuing authority simply had wrong information about me and couldn't issue a cert that matched me. This is a clue that sometimes, if rarely, it's not idiocy on the part of the user. The red tape between me and the issuing authority made it take a long time to solve this. I consider this issue closed and I've given all the information I can to help anyone else out who has this problem.